# knockout data-bind syntax in js ( not HTML)

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I understand I can create bindings using the following syntax in the dom:

```
 <span id="namespan" data-bind="text: personName">
```

Working example here:https://jsfiddle.net/m14mohda/

But can I create such a span element in js? i.e. using something like:

```
createSpans = function (){
    var s = document.createElement('span')
    s.id = "namespan"
    s.data-bind ="text: personName" -----> ????
    document.body.appendChild(s)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DOM Element API offers two ways of doing this. The more general one, that should work with any custom attribute is using the `setAttribute` method.

```
var s = document.createElement('span');
s.setAttribute("someAttribute", "someValue");
s.setAttribute("data-bind", "text: personName");
document.body.appendChild(s);
```

creates the element

```
<span someAttribute="someValue" data-bind="text: personName"></span>
```

Specifically for attributes that are *data-* prefixed, the specification includes the shorthand property accessor `dataset`.

```
var s = document.createElement('span');
s.dataset.someAttribute = "someValue"; // won't work as expected       
s.dataset.bind = "text: personName";
document.body.appendChild(s);
```

which creates the element

```
<span data-someAttribute="someValue" data-bind="text: personName"></span>
```

So you can see that `dataset` takes the *data-* prefix for granted. *data-* attribute values can then be accessed and assigned through `dataset` by stripping the *data-* part.

Comment: @Adi Only use [`.dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) if not targeting IE < 11, since it won't work.